# Azure SQL Database Group By not sorting

Tags: sql-server, sorting, azure, group-by, azure-sql-database

I have been using the following query in Windows Azure SQL Database, formerly SQL Azure, for a couple of years and it has always sorted by the group by field.

```
SELECT CAST(OccurredDate AS DATE) as OccurredDate, COUNT(*) AS [Count], COUNT(DISTINCT CreatedByUserId) AS NumOfUsers 
FROM [TableName] 
GROUP BY CAST(OccurredDate AS DATE)
```

Suddenly I ran this query today and it is no longer sorting the results.

I thought that GROUP BY always sorts the column its working on.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only database (that I know of) where `group by` is guaranteed to sort is MySQL.  And this feature has been deprecated (on the way out) since version 5.6 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, GROUP BY does not necessarily sort (while this was relatively reliable in SQL Server 2000, it still wasn't technically guaranteed; changes to the optimizer in 2005 changed this behavior such that it absolutely cannot be relied upon). If you were getting a specific order before, this was merely coincidence.

If you want a predictable order, **add an ORDER BY**. Period.

In this case, since ORDER BY is processed last, you don't have to repeat the expression, you can just use the alias from the SELECT list:

```
ORDER BY OccurredDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to elaborate on Aaron's response.  This isn't just an "optimizer" issue, it is an algorithmic issue.

When most people think of aggregation, they think of the following method:

1. Sort the data by the fields being aggregated (or walk through an index of the keys)
2. Walk through the data and identify where a group starts
3. Aggregate the values for all rows with the same key values (which are next to each other because of the sort)
4. Continue on to the next group

When you run this algorithm, one consequence is that the results are in order.  And this is the only algorithm provided by some databases (such as Access and MySQL).

The first point is that even this algorithm is not guaranteed to return data in order in a parallel (multi-threaded/multi-server) environment.  For instance, the first step in the environment might be to put all the strings starting with "A" on one processor (or thread), "B" on another, and so on.  Each processor then does the aggregation locally.

The important point is that the processors don't necessarily all finish at the same time.  For instance, "X" might finish long before "S".  And, that means that the results from "X" come back first.  Lo and behold, the results are not in order.

The second point is the more important.  SQL Server (and other intelligent databases) have other algorithms for doing aggregation.  The above algorithm is actually a hybrid -- first the values are "hashed", meaning that "similar" values are brought together on each processor, and then the rest are sorted for the aggregation.  The "hashing" guarantees that all keys with the same values are on the same processor.

This can be used for the final algorithm as well.  When you use a hash-based algorithm, there results are definitely not in sorted order, because no ordering ever occurs during the processing.  Happily, SQL Server supports hash-based algorithms for both aggregation and joins, so you wouldn't expect results to be sorted.

Comment: While true, I think it's important to note that the *algorithm* SQL Server 2000 used when grouping isn't really any different than it is now. It just so happened that they had a step where they arranged the results in the same order as the grouping, which is a step that has since been discarded, as it was deemed unnecessary (and I think prevented some of the optimizations that appeared).

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the intense details.  It makes sense, it's possible that quantity of data being processed has resulted in a different algorithm being used within Azure SQL DB.  I say this because this query has been in use for over 2 years and always returned the results ordered.

Comment: @user3260560 It could return the results ordered one way for 10 years. That doesn't mean it is by design, never mind guaranteed; and it can change in an instant based on at least a dozen different contributing factors. You were the victim of coincidence, nothing more. The Azure optimizer does not generate different query plans than other versions of SQL Server, and it certainly doesn't handle GROUP BY any differently. You need to trust us here, this didn't "stop working" when you moved to Azure. It just "happened" to work before.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the order might be related to Azure SQL's insistence on clustered indexes? But I may very we'll be wrong.